# ASP.NET Web API Load Assembly for bin folder and not the GAC

Tags: asp.net, .net, dll, assemblies, gac

I have a DLL that gets used in my code and when I hit the code that loads the DLL it throws an exception since the DLL is being loaded from the GAC.

The problem here is that the DLL has dependencies on other configuration files that need to be explicitly in the same folder but the exception that I got is:

> Could not find file
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\13cabfea\3fbdd7f4\assembly\dl3\4770150e\00f03f08_2249d301\default.config'

That file doesn't appear in the directoty but it is available in bin folder along with the DLL that I am trying to load.

With that being said, I read some documentation where says it is possible to load the DLL from a different location adding some changes in the web.config. This is what I tried

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MyDll.dll" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="6c02f43d970a9831" />
    <codeBase version="6.0.0.0" href="file://c:\inetpub\MyWebApp\bin\SubFolder\MyDll.dll"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

This approach didn't work since it is still throwing the exact same exception and I am running out of ideas... Is there a way I can use the DLL specified in the bin folder rather than the other location?

Comment: When you say "The solution didn't work...", what, exactly, do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that the same exception is thrown. It seems it is still looking for the DLL in the exact same directory (C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\etc...) instead of the \bin folder.

Comment: You should add that to your question.